# Creating a logical variable to identify the row within a group that is the minimum difference between two date-times

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Reproducible data sample `dput` output:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4), 
start = structure(c(1546326000, 
1546326060, 1546326270, 1546722600, 1546884300, 1546884720,  
1547102430), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
event_time = structure(c(1546326059, 1546326059, 1546326059, 
1546722930, 1546884480, 1546884480, NA), 
tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), 
.Names = c("id", "start", "event_time"), row.names = c(NA, -7L),
class = "data.frame")
```

I have some messy data that was merged from different sources, and am trying to create a new logical variable, which identifies which observation within the group (`id`) has the **least positive time difference between the `start` and `event_time` variables**, with a desire to do this within `dplyr`.

I've tried a few approaches but can't find something that works.  So far I'm thinking to create a new variable which calculates the difference in time between `event` and `start` or forces it to `NA` if that difference is negative, and then create the desired variable off of this.

The code:

```
dat %>% mutate(difference = ifelse(event_time > start, 
                                          event_time - start,
                                          NA)) %>%
    mutate(difference = as.integer(difference)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(is_closest = row_number() == which.min(difference))
```

This gives me an error though, which does not create the variable `is_closest`.

What I'm looking for in its simplest form is:

- code to create a variable identifying the closest value to some other reference value (another variable or some provided quantity including in this case, time) within a group of observations
- a more sensible way to identify the closest time within a group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(time_diff = start %--% event_time %>% as.numeric()) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    min_diff = time_diff[time_diff >= 0] %>% min(),
    min_diff_gr = time_diff == min_diff
  )
```

Comment: This does indeed work, @Pawel Chabros, was hoping to avoid an approach that required a reference variable since this seemed inefficient but also couldn't think of an approach which didn't have this and was still relatively readable code